# Can't import TableComponentJS in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

im working on a project and i have a problem. Im using Angular2, typescript, webpack 2.2 and im trying to use this table component:
[pyrite table](https://github.com/fagarbal/pyrite-table/)

The problem starts when i try to import this component in my component. I installed it with npm and thats work. But when i try to import it i use: `import * as Table from "pyrite-table";`

And then i try to use Table.load but i get an error: `index.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`

And that line is this:

```
export default module.exports = window.pyrite.Table = Table;
```

So my question is, how can i import this component in my project that is using typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I saw in the project [repo's](https://github.com/fagarbal/pyrite-table) readme the following loc:

```
import Table from 'pyrite-table';
```

Have you tried this one? Or:

```
import { Table } from 'pyrite-table';
```

Comment: Yes i tried it but doesnt work (It say: has no exported member 'Table'). I read on internet that you cant use module.exports with import but i dont know how to solve that.

Comment: So try this: create `declarations.d.ts` file somewhere in your `src` folder, add path to this file in your `tsconfig.json` and try again `import { Table } from 'pyrite-table';`. Content of the `declarations.d.ts` should be `declare module 'pyrite-table'`. For more details see www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: Need i write something in declarations.d.ts? And how i add path to this file in tsconfig? i create a empty declarations.d.ts in  src/history so i add: 
   "declaration": true,    "declarationDir": "history/declarations.d.ts",`
i dont know if its this correct

Comment: @Tibo Content of the `declarations.d.ts` should be `declare module 'pyrite-table'`. Follow this guide to add custom typing: goo.gl/96bAWr

Comment: Sorry i was sleeping. im still getting this error: index.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'

I follow the tutorial but it doesnt work

Comment: @Tido Are you considering the possibility to fork "pyrite-table" or use its _raw_ source?

Comment: @Tido I've resolved the issue by manually editing "pyrite-table" sources. I've fixed `Table` class export. Example can be found here: https://github.com/embarq/table-test. Just `npm install` and `npm start`